# Why is my tag edit for Krishna rejected as spam?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I made an edit suggestion to Krishna tag.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24833

The current info is:

> Krishna is considered as the eighth incarnation among ten principle
>   incarnations (Sanskrit दशावतार, IAST daśāvatāra) of Lord Vishnu.

I suggested the following change:

> Krishna is considered as the eighth incarnation among ten principle
>   incarnations (Sanskrit दशावतार, IAST daśāvatāra) of Lord Vishnu.
>   Krishna is also considered Svayam Bhagavan, source of all incarnations
>   by many.

[image]

And it is rejected giving the following reason:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

I don't understand how it is a valid reason to reject my edit. The reason is simply wrong.

But, I see following tags for Vishnu, Shiva and Radha.

Vishnu:

> The god of preservation, also called Narayana. Brahman in Vaishnavism

Shiva:

> Shiva (The auspicious one) is the "Destroyer" among the Trimurti. He
>   is considered as supreme Brahman according to Shaivism. Use this tag
>   to ask questions that concern about Shiva in any of his forms

Even, Radha, the consort of Krishna is mentioned as Adi Shakti

> Radha also called Radhika, Radharani and Radhikarani, is a Hindu
>   goddess who is almost always depicted alongside Krishna and features
>   prominently within the theology of today's Vallabha and Gaudiya
>   Vaishnava sects, which regards Radha as the original Goddess or
>   Shakti.

Considering all these, why is my edit rejected as promoting product and deliberately destructive? How is my tag edit any different from existing tags?

Comment: You should have mentioned "Krishna is Svayam Bhagavan, source of all incarnations as per Gaudiya vaishnavism" instead of generic statements.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think 4-5 sects consider , that's why I wrote many

Comment: It's not about how many sects. it is always better to mention sect or philosophy. Tag description should be as neutral as possible. It might have looked, you were promoting Krishna as supreme God in tag description. Hence they rejected.

Comment: Ah! I thought to edit the tag wiki but forgot. I suggest you to edit again by writing "Krishna is considered as Brahman by some sects" and elaborate it a little. Instead of "some" use specific names as others suggested. In my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20203/6981 I wrote some names which I know.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta I will edit tomorrow again

Answer (score 3):

Tag excerpt is **usage guidance** that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

Visit [Guidelines](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) from help-center:

> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
> - **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.**
>     In other words, what kinds of questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select your tag?

In earlier growing stage of bets sites, it is usually observed that users tend to write definition on tag excerpt. For instance the tag excerpt of [krishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/krishna) **should provide the guidance when to use this tag however we are rather defining the tag**. Here present tag excerpts identify the Krishna fine but we *should not concentrate much on descriptive definition* according to different sects in **excerpt**. We can do it (brief description) in full tag wiki (the text area after excerpt where markdown formatting is also supported)

In addition to your edit "Krishna is also considered Svayam Bhagavan, source of all incarnations by many." doesn't talk anything about when to use this tag, it tries to identify according to one belief of particular sect which may be taken as promoting particular sect or deity which is why I think your tag is rejected as spam.

Comment: Do you mean earlier tags were not defined properly?

Comment: Spam has altogether a different meaning. Spam carries penalties. Adding a line based on the previous tag excerpts is not spam. Which product was promoted here? May I know? Were the users spamming with Shiva, Vishnu and Radha also? The reason could be "No improvement whatsoever". Just another wrong review. I think the reviewers should also look at all the rejection reasons or improve the edit based on a newbie mistake. If you have doubt, look at [tag:alwar] history and how was it reviewed. Spam is too much for the edit.

Comment: Even I dont see any promotion here

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Agree that spam is bit much for this edit and "no improvement..." is better choice.

Comment: It should have been improved following previous tag excerpts. It was not the editor's mistake here. If you look at tag excerpts of many tags, they only contain description. Some contain plagiarized content from Wiki or other sources. Following guidelines, E.g Look at [tag:sathya-sai]. "Sathya Sai Baba who is believed by his followers to be the reincarnation of Sai Baba of Shirdi. " where is *guidance* which questions need the tag? Is this rejected as spam? What is the action if privileged users provide wrong excerpts or plagiarized content? Did the name of editor made them think it's spam?

Answer (score -1):

Had you proposed a consolidated wording such as the following taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna) along with names of a few sects like Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava that consider Kṛṣṇa as the supreme God, it had a better chance of getting approved.

> He is worshiped as the eighth avatar of the god Vishnu and also by some as the supreme God in his own right.

Simply adding an extra line to the current tag excerpt to me seemed like you were making a statement and/or promoting your sect. Although in retrospect I should have probably rejected as *[no improvement whatsoever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rejection-reasons/info)* ('changes are completely superfluous').

Suggest you try again with the above recommendations and also the ones in the other answer.